# What is the difference between Mozilla Firefox Beta and Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

Currently, the Mozilla Firefox Beta channel and the Developer Edition channel both offer the same version of Firefox.

What is the difference between the Beta version and the Developer Edition?

---

*Related, but different: [What is the difference between Mozilla Firefox and Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition?](https://superuser.com/questions/842601/what-is-the-difference-between-mozilla-firefox-and-mozilla-firefox-developer-edi) (this other question involves the release channel, not the Beta channel)*

Answer (score 3):

Firefox used to have 4 release channels, Nightly>Aurora>Beta>Release. A couple of years ago, they rebranded the Aurora channel as "Developer Edition", to appeal to developers and to get more people using it.

Recently, the Aurora channel was phased out, and Developer Edition is more or less just Beta, but set up with some different defaults, like theme and available developer tools.
DevEdition automatically sends feedback to Mozilla and allows
to load unsigned add-ons.

Both versions have the same code base but different configs.
Everything in Beta is meant to be shipped, but not in DevEdition.
Beta is basically the next release of Firefox,
about 6 weeks in advance.

DevEdition got the new debugger by default, forced multi process even if you had incompatible addons, had the new compact themes before they landed in beta.
It is just Beta with more experimental features and tools enabled
(see [the list](https://www.howtogeek.com/203225/what-is-the-difference-between-the-regular-and-developer-editions-of-firefox/)).

Comment: That linked list is merely a copy of the [SuperUser question on FF Standard vs Developer Edition](https://superuser.com/questions/842601/what-is-the-difference-between-mozilla-firefox-and-mozilla-firefox-developer-edi) referenced in the question posed above.  It's also just as out of date; there is no youtube video on the [FF Developer site](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), FF Hello and FF OS are dead, etc; it appears the differences between FF Beta and FF Developer Edition are as few as ever.